# Calling the controller method depending on the incoming parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement a certain functionality, but I do not know where to start. I will describe what I have.

**Backend**

```
public enum SourceType { Database, Folder }
public class DatabaseSource
{
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
public class FolderSource
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
}
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("source")]
    public void Post([FromBody]DatabaseSource source) //method one
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("source")]
    public void Post([FromBody]FolderSource source) //method two
    {
    }

}
```

**Frontend**

```
 export enum SourceType {
    Database,
    Folder
}
export class DatabaseSource {
    public ServerName: string;
    public DatabaseName: string;
}
export class FolderSource {
    public FolderName: string;
}

var source = new DatabaseSource();
source.ServerName = "serverName";
source.DatabaseName = "dbName";

var obj = {
    sourceType: SourceType.Database,
    source: source
};
```

Now imagine that I will send `obj` to the server. I want that specific controller method to be called depending on the enum. How can I do this?

P.S. The example is greatly simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is inconsistent for what you've specified in code.

On the front-end you are describing an object which has a `sourceType` field and a `source` object property, while on the backend you're overloading the `ApiController` method and mapping different REST object resources to a single HTTP method and endpoint (which I believe will not work).

There is no magic way for the `ApiController` to use your `enum` property to differentiate between the object types automatically.

A simpler (and better) implementation would be to have separate `ApiController` classes for your `Database` and `Folder` source object POST calls. This follows the principle of REST API design where you are essentially mapping basic CRUD operations to the HTTP methods with object types.

If your intention is to perform an operation based on these parameter objects, then clarify the intention via the API routing for the endpoint as below:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ETLLoad/Database/source")]
    public void Post([FromBody]DatabaseSource source) //method one
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ETLLoad/Folder/source")]
    public void Post([FromBody]FolderSource source) //method two
    {
    }

}
```